# use clients on terminal server

Tags: ltsp, ltsp-client, terminal-server

I installed a terminal server on ubuntu using ltsp-standalone and client with the i386.
I did the network configuration also.

But the question now is how do I have to make clients and/or how can they log in on my terminal server.
Is it necessary to use a domain-name?